# Does Moq.Mock.Verify() compare parameters using identity or .Equals()?

Tags: c#, moq

In a command like

```
var mockObj = new Mock<MyObject>()
var anotherObj = Utilities.DoStuff();
// some tests...
mockObj.Verify(foo => foo.someMethod(anotherObj));
```

Does Moq use comparison by identity or by using `.Equals()` to determine whether `someMethod()` was ever called with `anotherObj` as a parameter? In other words, does the object I indicate as a parameter for `foo.someMethod()` have to be the exact same object that `someMethod()` was called with earlier for the verification to pass, or does it only have to be one that is equal to `anotherObj`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`Moq` will compare by identity, it will be looking for the exact instance that you specified using identity. If this is not what you want, and you are looking for `equals` comparison instead, you can use `It.Is`:

```
mockObj.Verify(foo => foo.someMethod(It.Is<MyObject>(m => m.Equals(anotherObj))));
```